# Cocoon nested forms not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have added nested forms with Cocoon but the attributes are simply not being sent and nothing is being saved. I tried playing around with plural/singular but no luck so far. The best I could get it so far was that it sent parameters when I make the f.simple_fields_for in singular but then still only 1 gets sent (only the first added one) and I get 'unpermitted parameter vacancyschedule', but as far as I know I'm following the docs naming wise.
Any help is appreciated.

My setup:

**Models**

vacancy.rb

```
has_many :vacancyschedules, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :vacancyschedules, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

vacancyschedule.rb

```
belongs_to :vacancy
```

**Controller**

```
def vacancy_params
  params.require(:vacancy).permit(:address, :name, :street, :city, :zip, :country, :description, :jobtype_id, :recruiter_id, :start_date, :end_date, :start_hour, :end_hour, :skill_id, :wage_cents, :tag_list, :jobterm_id, vacancyschedule_attributes: [:start_date, :end_date, :start_hour, :end_hour, :address, :_destroy, :id])
end
```

**Regular form**

```
 = simple_form_for @vacancy do |f| 
   ... regular fields that are saving correctly ...
   .vacancyschedules
     = f.simple_fields_for :vacancyschedules do |vacancyschedule|
       =render "vacancyschedule_fields", :f, :vacancyschedule
    .links
      =link_to_add_association 'add schedule', f, vacancyschedules
```

**Partial**

```
.nested-fields
  .field
    =f.input :start_hour, as: :time
  .field
    =f.input :end_hour, as: :time

  =link_to_remove_association "", f
```

**EDIT** As mentioned above,

When I do simple_fields_for :vacancyschedule I get some parameters (although its only the first one, ignores if more forms are added)

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iF/6usHuIszbWH+JCERMZHKPGQu59VrLePlyR1Xea8hqlTbGdgCRJmG9bwh
XlCczK7xLK3JW96vkngwY5PzYJg==", "vacancy"=>{"recruiter_id"=>"2", "name"=>"", "address"=>"", "description"=>"", "jobtype_id"=>"", "jobterm_id"=>"", 
"wage_cents"=>"", "vacancyschedule"=>{"start_hour(1i)"=>"2015", "start_hour(2i)"=>"12", "start_hour(3i)"=>"9", "start_hour(4i)"=>"09", 
"start_hour(5i)"=>"00", "end_hour(1i)"=>"2015", "end_hour(2i)"=>"12", "end_hour(3i)"=>"9", "end_hour(4i)"=>"17", "end_hour(5i)"=>"00", 
"start_date"=>"1/1/1"}}, "commit"=>"Create Vacancy"}
 Unpermitted parameter: vacancyschedule
```

When in plural, nothing is sent..

**Update 2**

New and create methods in my vacancycontroller

```
  def new
    @vacancy = Vacancy.new
    # @vacancyschedules = @vacancy.vacancyschedules
  end

  def create
    @vacancy = Vacancy.create(vacancy_params)
    # Vacancyschedule.create(vacancyschedule_params)
    redirect_to show_created_vacancy_path(@vacancy)
  end
```

As far as I can read only the new and create of the "mother" model are needed. I also tested before by trying to add the schedule there without success..

Comment: can you paste a snip of your sent params?

Comment: can you now show your `new` and `create` method in the vacancy controller?

Comment: Updated my main post

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the render part wrong I suppose:

## Regular form

```
 = simple_form_for @vacancy do |f| 
   ... regular fields that are saving correctly ...
   .vacancyschedules
     = f.simple_fields_for :vacancyschedules do |vacancyschedule|
       =render "vacancyschedule_fields", f: vacancyschedule
    .links
      =link_to_add_association 'add schedule', f, vacancyschedules
```

Comment: Tried that, still not submitting anything.

Comment: Can you do 'puts params' at the top of your create method and post a screenshot of your server log?

Answer (score 1):

```
#vacancy.rb:
has_many :vacancyschedules, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :vacancyschedules,
  reject_if: :all_blank,
  allow_destroy: true
```

and in vacancyschedule.rb:

```
#vacancyschedule.rb:
belongs_to :vacancy
```

In the vacancy controller:

```
#vacancy_controller.rb:
def create
  @vacancy = Vacancy.new(vacancy_params)
  if @vacancy.save
    redirect_to :back, notice: "vacancy successfully created."
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private
def vacancy_params
  params.require(:vacancy).permit(:address, :name, :street, :city..., vacancyschedules_attributes: [:start_date, :end_date, :start_hour...])
end
```

In your view:

```
#_form.html.haml
= simple_form_for @vacancy do |f| 
  ... regular fields that are saving correctly ...
  .vacancyschedules
    = f.simple_fields_for :vacancyschedules do |vacancyschedule|
      =render "vacancyschedule_fields", f: vacancyschedule
    .links
      =link_to_add_association 'add schedule', f, vacancyschedules

#vacancyschedule_fields.html.haml
.nested-fields
  .field
    =f.input :start_hour, as: :time
  .field
    =f.input :end_hour, as: :time

  =link_to_remove_association "X", f
```

This should work well for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your strong parameters definition (as posted here) is wrong: you write `vacancyschedule_attributes` (singular) and it has to match the association, so it should be `vacancyschedules_attributes`.

Completely unrelated side-note: I would prefer class name `VacancySchedule`, and thus association-name `vacancy_schedules`. That is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

First off, thank you all for your help.

I found out the code itself was not wrong.
For some reason the surrounding divs were messing with the javascript that cocoon provides.
I stripped all the divs / styling and it submits and saves correctly.
Next challenge for me is to add styling step by step and see where the issue occurs.